# Como pegar imagens no XML CDATA e DESCRIPTION

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, feed

Eu tenho alguns arquivos xml, e varios deles as imagens das noticias estão dentro da description, em um deles a imagem fica dentro do CDATA, na hora que eu retorno o array a description não aparece nenhum elemento conforme a foto:

[image: array gerado pelo SimpleXmlElement]

em outro caso a imagem ja vem inserida dentro da description que não contem um CDATA como na imagem abaixo:

[image: No caso a imagem ai é a onça]

nós dois casos eu não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de manipular essas imagens da maneira que eu quiser, queria saber se poderiam me ajudar,

vou postar meu codigo aqui também, por enquanto ele ta simples ainda estou desenvolvendo ele, e não consigo sair dessa parte.

```
 $feedwwf = file_get_contents('https://www.wwf.org.br/rss/rss.cfm?B5ABCD22- 
A9C2-3BB4-44189EF9064E5481',LIBXML_NOCDATA);    
 $rsswwf = new SimpleXMLElement($feedwwf);
  $wwf = $rsswwf->channel->item[0];
  $desc = $wwf->description;


$feedg1 = file_get_contents('http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/');
$rssg1 = new SimpleXMLElement($feedg1);
$g1 = $rssg1->channel->item[0];
$desc = $g1->description->attributes('img') ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP Oferece uma classe bem abrangente para manipular XML o DOMDocument

[ http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php ]

Você pode manipular o documento da seguinte forma:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/');

# localizando um elemento dentro do xml
$url = $dom->getElementsByTagName('url');

# alterando o primeiro item ou seja o primeiro elemento
$url->item(0)->nodeValue = 'imagem_teste.png';

$dom->saveXML();
```